# Plot a graph from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary with following key-value pairs.

```
21 {'05': {'210527_NS5001_01_AHT': 244.64}}
22 {'11': {'221101_NS5002_02_AHV': 173.79, '221104_NS5002_03_AHC': 192.17}}
23 {'03': {'230331_NS5002_04_AH3': 222.73}, '04': {'230405_NS5002_05_AHG': 223.97}}
```

Where, 21, 22, 23 are years, 05, 11, 03, and 04 are months and strings containing NS are run ids and the float values are densities.

I wish to plot the trends in changing density value for each year and month without the run ids. I have tried following code however it does not seem to generate plots I want

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

for year, months in dateDensity.items():
    x = [int(month) for month in months.keys()]
    for month, runids in months.items():
        densities = runids.values()
        plt.plot(x, densities, label=year, marker='o')
    #plt.plot(x, y, label=year, marker='o')


plt.title('Density Plot over Time')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('density_plot.pdf')
```

How can I generate this plot where there is a label for every year and if there are multiple density values for same months it should be included in the plot ?

[image]

Comment: What do you want in that case?  An average?

Comment: No, I want all the densities plotted out for multiple values of same month as the run ids are unique. Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? This is currently not valid python

Comment: This code snippet is part of a script which I am working on. I have generated a csv file with the data which I have shown in table in original question.

Comment: From the table you have separated out year, month, density data. You could now combine year and month into a DateTime value and then use a scatter plot of density against these DT values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  You can certainly do a scatter plot, where each year is a different colored dot.  Perhaps you should draw by hand the plot you're expecting and show us.

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted the structure of your original dictionary into a flat representation, where each entry will become a single row in a table. Then I wrapped that in a `DataFrame` and created the plot.

[image]

[image]

Imports and data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    21: {'05': {'210527_NS5001_01_AHT': 244.64}
         },
    22: {'11': {'221101_NS5002_02_AHV': 173.79, '221104_NS5002_03_AHC': 192.17}
         },
    23: {'03': {'230331_NS5002_04_AH3': 222.73},
         '04': {'230405_NS5002_05_AHG': 223.97}
         }
}
```

Re-organise the data so that it is flat rather than nested, and wrap in a dataframe.

```
data_rows = []
for year, year_dict in data.items():
    for month, month_dict in year_dict.items():
        for run_id, density in month_dict.items():
            row = {
                'year': year,
                'month': month,
                'runID': run_id,
                'density': density
            }
            print(row)
            data_rows.append(row)

table = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)

#Scatter of density vs month using pandas in-built plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
discrete_colormap = plt.get_cmap('copper', table.year.nunique()) #optional discrete colormap for year

table.plot(x='month', y='density', kind='scatter', marker='s', c='year',
           cmap=discrete_colormap, s=50, figsize=(5, 2.5))
```

You could alternatively create the plot manually using `plt.scatter(...)`.